# Upload cert file using python API

Tags: python, api, rest

How to upload a cert file using python API.
I have some input data to pass along with uploading the file.
I am using the api code as below-

```
url = 'https://someurl.com/'
data= {'operation':
          {'Details':
              {'AccountName': 'Example1',
               'Owner':'root',
               }}}
files = open("filename.txt", "rb")
response = requests.post(url,data, files={"form_field_name": files}, verify=False)
```

when the above code is executed, I get the **response[200]** as output, but the file is not uploaded.
Can someone help me to figure out what am I missing here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the file path is correct: Double-check that the file you are trying to upload ("filename.txt") is in the correct location and that the path to the file is correct. You can print the contents of the file to verify that it is being read correctly:

```
with open("filename.txt", "rb") as f:
    file_content = f.read()
print(file_content)
```

Check the server response: After making the request, print the server response to seeing if there are any error messages or indications that the file upload was unsuccessful

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, files={"form_field_name": files}, verify=False)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Check the file size limit You can try uploading a smaller file to see if that works.

Try using a different form field name: The name of the form field for the file may not be "form_field_name". You can try using a different name or checking the API documentation to see what the correct name is.

This is your cURL to python script example:

```
import requests

url = 'https://somesite.com:7272/restapi/json/v1/resources'
auth_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
headers = {
    'AUTHTOKEN': auth_token,
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
file = {'file': open('testcert.txt', 'rb')}
input_data = {
    'INPUT_DATA': '{"operation":{"Details":{"RESOURCEGROUPNAME":"SomeResourceGroup","RESOURCENAME":"Test Cert Ex1","ACCOUNTNAME":"Example1","RESOURCETYPE":"File Store","PASSWORD":"*****","NOTES":"Testing API", "OWNERNAME":"root"}}}'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=file, data=input_data, verify=False)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print('File uploaded successfully.')
else:
    print(f'Error uploading file. Status code: {response.status_code}')
    print(response.text)
```

sets the url and auth_token variables based on your curl command.

sets the headers dictionary with the required headers, including the AUTHTOKEN and Content-Type headers.

creates a dictionary file containing the file to be uploaded. The open function is used to open the file in binary mode.

creates a dictionary input_data containing the input data to be sent along with the file. Note that the value for the 'INPUT_DATA' key is a string containing a JSON object.

sends a POST request to the API endpoint with the headers, files, and data parameters, and sets verify to False to disable SSL verification. It then checks the response status code and prints an appropriate message.

Comment: Thank you @ma9 for the quick response.
I tried priting the contents of the file and i am able to print it. So there is no issue with the filename or file location.

However, I am only getting the response code as 200, without any response text.

Comment: Use a tool like Postman or cURL to manually send the same API request and see if you receive any response text.

Comment: can try printing the response.content attribute instead of response.text.

Comment: This is my curl statement
```curl -X POST -k -H "AUTHTOKEN:xxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F 'file=testcert.txt' -F 'INPUT_DATA={"operation":{"Details":{"RESOURCEGROUPNAME":"SomeResourceGroup","RESOURCENAME":"Test Cert Ex1","ACCOUNTNAME":"Example1","RESOURCETYPE":"File Store","PASSWORD":"*****","NOTES":"Testing API", "OWNERNAME":"root"}}}' "https://somesite.com:7272/restapi/json/v1/resources```

Comment: The above curl command works for me, when I am trying to adapt it into python api, it is not working

Comment: I update the answer with curl to a python script I hope that help

Comment: The above code gives the error that the JSON string of the INPUT data is not correct. I tried to validate the JSON but that also didnt solve the issue.
Anyways, Thanks a lot for your continuous effort to help me